# Visual Studio 2019 for Mac: debugger doesn't connect to iOS device

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, visual-studio-mac

I'm trying to debug a long suffered Xamarin app using visual studio 2019 on a brand new MacBook Pro (Mojave).

The solution builds, transfers to the device and starts the app, but the debugger will connect neither via cable or wifi. A dummy project in Visual Studio for Mac won't connect either, though a dummy project in xcode will.

VS just says "waiting for the debugger to connect to ... on port 10000 via Wifi"

Here are my VS details:

```
Visual Studio Community 2019 for Mac
Version 8.1.3 (build 19)
Installation UUID: 76ac8505-c20b-434f-95d4-c8266d3517f2
    GTK+ 2.24.23 (Raleigh theme)
    Xamarin.Mac 5.6.0.25 (d16-0 / 50f75273)

    Package version: 518010028

Mono Framework MDK
Runtime:
    Mono 5.18.1.28 (2018-08/223ea7ef92e) (64-bit)
    Package version: 518010028

NuGet
Version: 5.0.2.5988

.NET Core
Runtime: /usr/local/share/dotnet/dotnet
Runtime Versions:
    3.0.0-preview6-27804-01
    2.1.11
    2.1.9
SDK: /usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/3.0.100-preview6-012264/Sdks
SDK Versions:
    3.0.100-preview6-012264
    2.1.700
    2.1.505
MSBuild SDKs: /Library/Frameworks/Mono.framework/Versions/5.18.1/lib/mono/msbuild/Current/bin/Sdks

Xamarin.Profiler
Version: 1.6.10
Location: /Applications/Xamarin Profiler.app/Contents/MacOS/Xamarin Profiler

Updater
Version: 11

Xamarin.Android
Not Installed

Microsoft Mobile OpenJDK
Java SDK: Not Found

Android Designer EPL code available here:
https://github.com/xamarin/AndroidDesigner.EPL

Android Device Manager
Version: 1.2.0.44
Hash: aac645b
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-1
Build date: 2019-05-29 19:55:24 UTC

Xamarin Designer
Version: 16.1.0.467
Hash: f1657e133
Branch: remotes/origin/d16-1-new-document-model
Build date: 2019-06-18 21:57:42 UTC

Apple Developer Tools
Xcode 10.2.1 (14490.122)
Build 10E1001

Xamarin.Mac
Xamarin.Mac not installed. Can't find /Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.Mac.framework/Versions/Current/Version.

Xamarin.iOS
Version: 12.10.0.157 (Visual Studio Community)
Hash: 6bd94753
Branch: d16-1
Build date: 2019-06-12 17:28:47-0400

Xamarin Inspector
Version: 1.4.3
Hash: db27525
Branch: 1.4-release
Build date: Mon, 09 Jul 2018 21:20:18 GMT
Client compatibility: 1

Build Information
Release ID: 801030019
Git revision: 2d04b0145da8aa946d2cc9898fe2a59484e4f3f4
Build date: 2019-06-26 15:34:25+00
Build branch: release-8.1
Xamarin extensions: de240bddd6d1f96bfb1e7d11ce7ac5398956fe1d

Operating System
Mac OS X 10.14.5
Darwin 18.6.0 Darwin Kernel Version 18.6.0
    Thu Apr 25 23:16:27 PDT 2019
    root:xnu-4903.261.4~2/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Help.

Comment: Have you tried WiFi debugging on a new project in Xcode? Does that work?

Comment: yep that works fine

Comment: I just recently had this issue too. It fails silently. You need to look for the error on the Build Output tab that appears at the bottom after pressing start

Comment: thanks @iSpain17, that put me on the right track. I thought I had these infuriating profiles/certs figured out and installed, but it turns out I had the wrong one again. VS hiding the error didn't help, but you did! If you set an answer up I'll accept it.

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These errors are usually hidden now in VS 2019 for Mac sadly. You need to look at the **Build Output** window to exactly determine what causes this malfunction.

The behavior you described does not belong to a specific kind of error, it only means that VS didn't visually show its description, rather got stuck because the run process failed while trying to put the build on the physical device.

Comment: when you put it like that, I feel like quite an idiot ;-)

Comment: That has not been my intention :D It is rather the clunkiness of VS for Mac and Xamarin unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

First of all , ensure xcode and visual studio version the latest.

Also try

1. Manually start the application by tapping the icon
2. Deleting the app from the device and redeploying it
3. Rebooting the device
4. Change Debugger port

Check this thread : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/94088/xamarin-studio-waiting-for-debugger-to-connect-to-the-ios-simulator